# Using request when it is not passed as parameter

Tags: python, django

I am trying to overwrite a method, however, it does not take `request` as parameter. Basically, I want to add a condition depending on the request user and I can add a small example:

```
def has_to_be_overwritten(queryset=None, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        do magic
    else:
        no magic
```

Is this possible or should I look for a different solution?

Comment: Where is this method used - is it in a class or free standing? Any reason it can't take the request (if it's not already available on a class instance)?

Comment: [export](http://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_resources.html?highlight=exclude#import_export.resources.Resource.export) is the method I would like to add the condition to as I am trying to set the fields that are being exported depending on the request user.

Comment: Probably be useful mentioning that in an [edit] to your question... anyway - do you have a request object or a user object (or even just a "is_superuser" flag) you can just pass to the function? Its signature is fairly broad...

Comment: It is an action in the admin interface, so I have a request user that I can pass.

Comment: There you go then... :)

Comment: @JonClements not sure whether this is the best solution, but i will probably go with `request = kwargs.pop("request")`.